# How to create an instance with nested array of object in node js

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose-schema

My model is

```
const profileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fName: String,
  lName: String,
  address: String,
  webLinks: [
    {
      name: String,
      link: String,
    },
  ],
  },
  profileImage: String,
  images: [String],
  
  block: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },

});
```

for the controller I have

```
The data I am getting from req.body for web links is in the following form(through form data of postman)
```

[ '{name:abc,link:link11.com}', '{name:def,link:link22.com}' ]

```
but when I am trying to create an instance using
```

const profile = await Profile.create({
fName,
lName,
address,
webLinks,
images
})

The error I am getting is

```
validation failed: webLinks: Cast to embedded failed for value \"'{name:abc,link:link11.com}'\" (type string) at path \"webLinks\""
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the type of data inside the array it is a string instead of an object.
hope I answered your question

Comment: How can we parse in into an object. JSON.parse wont work here

Comment: Do you have body parse middleware?
kindly check the type of that variable (webLinks)

Comment: The actual error was using express-fileupload for parsing multipart form.